# Es seguro usar malloc y free sin alineación de memoria en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy construyendo mi propio recolector de basura para administrar la memoria de forma inteligente, la razon es simple, estoy usando listas enlazadas que requieren muchas operaciones de inserción y eliminación de elementos y eso provoca muchas llamadas a `new` y `delete`.

La solución mas elegante que se me ocurrió es usar un gran bloque de memoria sin inicializar para proveer punteros individuales cada vez que se solicite memoria y cuando se solicite liberar, simplemente quedará disponible para una solicitud futura y de esa forma reciclo la memoria aumentando el rendimiento.

```
void* memoria= std::malloc(sizeof(miTipo)*num_elementos);
```

La memoria se provee usando `static_cast<miTipo*>(memoria)+posicion` que es una combinación de conversión de puntero con aritmética de punteros para acceder a diferentes posiciones del bloque.

**La parte cuestionable es la siguiente:** Para inicializar el objeto hago uso de `std::construct_at(pointerT,args...)` que permite llamar al constructor que coincida con los argumentos y luego `std::destroy_at(pointerT)` sirve para llamar al destructor y dejar el bloque sin inicialización, estas funciones son provistos por la directiva `#include <memory>`. **EL choque cerebral lo recibí** cuando descubrí la existencia de algo llamado **alineación de memoria**,  nunca supe de esto porque **mi maquina corre bien y nunca a mostrado fallas**.

No entiendo esto:

```
alignof(T)
alignment_of(T)
typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta: SI, es seguro

Todos los datos almacenados en memoria tienen una alineación por defecto. Estos mecanismos te permiten especificar otro tipo de alineación más conveniente para tus necesidades:

- Para optimizar el funcionamiento de la caché
- Comunicaciones de datos entre diferentes arquitecturas hardware
- ...

Pero como norma general podríamos decir que la alineación aplicada por el compilador es válida para la inmensa mayoría de los casos.

De hecho se puede ver cómo funciona la alineación nativa:

```
struct Foo
{
  int a;
  char b;
  float c;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    size_t p1 = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&f.a);
    size_t p2 = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&f.b);
    size_t p3 = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&f.c);
 
    std::cout << p2 - p1 << '\n' << p3 - p2 << '\n';
}
```

Este programa genera la siguiente salida:

```
4
4
```

Aquí se puede ver cómo `b`, que es de tipo `char`, pese a ocupar únicamente un byte, está separada 4 bytes de la siguiente variable.

Dicho esto, vamos con las funciones:

- `alignof` te indica la alineación aplicada para un tipo dado
- `alignment_of` una plantilla que se limita a devolver lo que diga `alignof`
- `std::aligned_storage` permite especificar cómo se va a guardar una colección de objetos en memoria. Dichos objetos ocuparán cada uno `sizeof(T)` bytes, mientras que la alineación de los objetos será de `alignof(T)` bytes.

Para entender la diferencia entre `sizeof` y `alignof`, podemos probar el siguiente ejemplo:

```
struct Foo
{
    int   i;
    float f;
    char  c;
};

struct Foo2
{
    int   i;
    double f;
    char  c;
};
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Alignment of"  "\n"
        "- class Foo  : " << alignof(Foo)  << ' ' << sizeof(Foo)  << "\n"
        "- class Foo2 : " << alignof(Foo2) << ' ' << sizeof(Foo2) << "\n";
}
```

Este programa genera la siguiente salida:

```
Alignment of
- class Foo  : 4 12
- class Foo2 : 8 24
```

Aquí `sizeof` nos está devolviendo cuánto ocupa el objeto en memoria, mientras que `alignof` nos indica cuánto espacio ocupa de forma efectiva cada variable.

La relación, por tanto, entre ambos valores sería:

```
sizeof(T) = alignof(T) * numero_de_variables;
```

Esta regla no te la tomes al pie de la letra porque, por ejemplo, con clases y herencia, la situación se complica.